# How to convert proceedural code with DI to OO code

Tags: java, cdi

I have a project using CDI. A container managed service class that has a list of states.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class StateService {

    @Inject
    MailService mailService;

    //Inject some other stuff

    private Map<String, State> state = new HashMap<String, State>();

    public void makeStateTransition(StateChange stateChange) {
        State currentState = state.get(stateChange.getKey());
        switch (currentState.stateType) {
            case STATE1:
                handleState1Transition(stateChange);
            case STATE2:
                handleState2Transition(stateChange);
            case STATE3:
                handleState3Transition(stateChange);
        }
    }

    private void handleState1Transition(StateChange stateChange) {
        //Do some stuff to handle state and use injected mailsender to send some email
        mailService.sendEmail("Send some email");
        //if some criteria is right create a new state and set it in the map
        State newState = new State();
        //Set some variable
        state.put(stateChange.getKey(), newState);
    }

    private void handleState2Transition(StateChange stateChange) {
        //Do stuff similar to above, maybe use other injected fields
    }

    private void handleState3Transition(StateChange stateChange) {
        //Do stuff similar to above
    }
}

public class State {

    public enum StateType {
        STATE1, STATE2, STATE3
    }

    public StateType stateType;

    //Bunch of other properties


}
```

This turns out to be terribly proceedural. I refactored it to try to make it more OO.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class StateService {

    @Inject
    MailService mailSerice;

    //Inject some other stuff

    private Map<String, State> state = new HashMap<String, State>();

    public void makeStateTransition(StateChange stateChange) {
        State currentState = state.get(stateChange.getKey());
        State newState = currentState.handleStateChange(stateChange, mailService);
        state.put(stateChange.getKey(), newState);
    }
}
```

Now StateService does not need to know all state transitions

```
public abstract class State {
    //Some protected fields shared by all states

    public abstract State handleStateChange(StateChange stateChange, MailService mailService);
}

public class SomeState extends State {

    //Some properties specific to this state

    public State handleStateChange(StateChange stateChange, MailService mailSerice) {
        //Do some stuff to handle state and use injected mailsender to send some email
        mailSerice.sendEmail("Send some email");
        return new SomeOtherState();
    }
}
```

This leads to much nicer code, especially as the number of possible states grow. 
The problem is getting the injected mailsender into the right state that needs it. Some states might not need it and others might need something else. Because the states are not created by the container they can not use injection themselves.
Passing injected fields in the constructor of a state is a possibility but then the injected object might get "stale" inside the unmanaged state?

I resorted to sending it as an argument in the method call, that way it should always be "fresh". Very cumbersome if many injections needs to be sent as arguments and feels wrong in some way.

How would you propose how to handle the injected resources needed by the state objects in this example?

Please disregard any threading issues in the class.

Comment: You may want to post this on codereview.stackexchange